# Why I can not write .ppm P3 file with fwrite on a buffer in C++, only hard-coded text?

Tags: c++, ppm

Here is the code, but I get error, black image..

```
FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    //fprintf(fp, "P3\n4 4 \n255\n 168  50  50 168  50  51  168  50  51 15  0 15 0  0  0 0 15  7  255 255 255    0  0  0 0  0  0    0  0  0    0 15  7    0  0  0 15  0 15    0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0");
    fprintf(fp, "P3\n4 4 \n255 \n");

    unsigned char* newBuffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(4*4*3);

    int br = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 * 4; i++) {
        newBuffer[br++] = 168;
        newBuffer[br++] = 50;
        newBuffer[br++] = 50;

    }

    fwrite(newBuffer, sizeof(unsigned char), (size_t)(4*4*3), fp);
    fclose(fp);
```

When I use commented line instead of newBuffer it works perfectly, and I do not know what is the difference when I write bytes in one string and when I write bytes with newBuffer.. Any help, thanks in advance..

Comment: This pure C-Code. With C++ you can do what you want.

Comment: `newBuffer[br++] = 168;` does not do what you want. You actually want a text file but you your code is creating a binary file instead. Here is the ppm format: [http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html)

Comment: If you want to write binary data for the pixels you need to make a P6 format file.

Comment: Thanks a lot on the answers, I use now fprintf and it works nice..